# Mount fails and don't timeout

Tags: mount

I've a script that runs every 30m and check if /mnt/controlurg is mounted. If not, it tries to mount it and get some files from it (it's a Windows drive). Before 12.04 I didn't had problems but now when the script can't mount (for any reason) the remote drive the mount command don't end and keeps as a background process. And even worst, a new zombie background mount process is created every 30m and the CPU Load Average is getting high (now is 44%!!).

Checking for running processes I get multiple entries like that:

```
root     29458 29420  0 08:35 ?        00:00:00 mount /mnt/controlurg
root     29459 29458  0 08:35 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mount.cifs //controlurg/c$ /mnt/controlurg -o rw,noauto,user=root,passwd=example,utf8
```

- How can I kill that processes? "kill -9 29459" doesn't work.
- Why these processes don't timeout? How can I kill this failed mounts automatically?

The interesting fragment of /opt/scripts/sftpcont.shl:

```
cat $SCRIPT/computers.dat | while read line
do
echo `date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` ": Copying to ${line} with samba"
isalive=`ping -q -c1 $line| grep "1 received" |wc -l`
if [ $isalive!= "0" ]
 then
  mount /mnt/$line
  rm /mnt/$linea/contingenciasap/*
  cp $SCRIPT/fitxers/sapfitcrip.zip /mnt/$line/contingenciasap
  umount /mnt/$line
fi
done
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you show your script. But anyway, you have to use exit command like:

```
mount <partition> /mnt/controlurg || exit 1
```

This command just will stop running script. You can show some message(or write to log file) like:

```
mount <partition> /mnt/controlurg || eval 'echo "Error mounting partition" 1>&2; exit 1'

mount <partition> /mnt/controlurg || eval 'echo "Error mounting partition\n" >> mount.log; exit 1'
```

To kill all processes use `killall` command.

Comment: The killall command (killall mount) only kill the processes "mount /mnt/controlurg", but not the /sbin/mount.cifs ... So the CPU Load keeps getting high. I tried kill -9, killall... restart samba, ... and the background processes remain :(


I've added the script in the post. I can't use the "|| exit 1" because I don't want to stop the script when a mount fails, the script have to keep going.

Comment: Ok. Than you have to use break command or continue.

Comment: Probably, continue is what you are searching for(read another line and try mount it). Use :

||continue

Comment: Oh! Sorry I forgot. Try killall /sbin/mount.cifs. Hope it help you.